# Computer science, software engineer/developer, and programmer

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico, vocabulario

When visiting Spanish-speaking countries, I've been told various ways to translate these terms:

- Computer Science (as in a university degree program)
- Software Engineer
- Software Developer
- Programmer

What is the most accurate way to translate these terms?

Comment: I think this question should at minimum be split into separate questions, one for each term, as it is obvious it has generated varying degrees of discussion on each separate term.

Comment: I'm also concerned that this question is essentially asking for simple dictionary translations of terms as previously discussed on [meta](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/12/12), and therefore perhaps not a very good example of an expert-level question anyway.

Comment: @Flimzy: IMO, all the discussion shows it's more complex than a simple dictionary translation. Granted, it's not really "expert-level," but I think it's something I'd have trouble understanding completely just using a dictionary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here in Chile, they are translated as:

- *Ciencias de la Computación.*
- *Ingeniero de Software.*
- *Desarrollador (o Ingeniero) de Software.*
- *Programador.*

For example: *Magíster en Ciencias de la Computación*, or *Magíster en Ciencias de la Ingeniería, mención Computación*.

---

**UPDATE**:
Do not confuse *Informática* and *Computación*:

- ***Informática***: Relates to the management of information, in a concrete and practical sense.
- ***Computación***: Relates to the "Computer science", a theoretical field closely related to mathematics. To get a grasp of it, StackExchange already has a Questions & Answers site: [Theoretical computer science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

So, studying *Informática* or *Ciencias de la computación* are two **different** things.

Comment: Hi, I'm from Uruguay, do you NOT use the term `Ingeniero de sistemas`?

Comment: @Trufa: "Ingeniero de sistemas" (systems engineer) and "ingeniero de software" (software engineer) are *not* equivalent.

Comment: Are they really capitalized like that?? Spanish usually uses capital letters far less than English.

Comment: @EduardoLeón: At least in Colombia, _ingeniería de sistemas_ is a blanket term for most software-related fields and thus the closest equivalent to _Software Engineering_, _Computer Engineering_, or _Computer Science_. Read the degree descriptions from [Universidad de los Andes](http://sistemas.uniandes.edu.co/sitio/pregrados) and [Universidad de Antioquia](http://sistemas.udea.edu.co/index.php/curriculo/plan-de-estudios/version-1) as examples. Could that also be the case in Uruguay?

Answer (score 3):

In Spain all but the first are as Nicolás states, but CompSci is *informática superior*. (Although you might get some degrees which claim to be Computer Science but are really *informática técnica*).

Answer (score 1):

Como bien dice Peter Taylor en su contestación las traducciones hechas por los compañeros no son correctas:

Computer Science (as in a university degree program)
En castellano se traduciría como Ingeniero Informático o Ingeniero en Informática. En España no existe la titulación Ingeniero en Computación o Ingeniero del Software como en otros países, sino que el término que se acuñó es el que te comento. Yo de hecho soy Ingeniero informático. Un dato curioso relacionado con esto es que en España a los PC no se les llama computadoras personales, ni computadoras sino que se les llama ordenadores. (Y tiene gracia puesto que uno de los trabajos que más tienen que realizar los ordenadores es el de ordenar datos).

Software Engineer: Ingeniero del Software. Este término es correcto y existen puestos de trabajo con este nombre. De hecho durante la carrera hay varias asignaturas que se llaman Ingeniería del Software y probablemente sería el término más correcto para definir el trabajo que realizamos (no sólo en España, en todo el mundo y es una cuestión que se ha discutido muchísimas veces en importantes congresos)

Software Developer: Desarrollador Software o Programmer programador. Dos términos diferentes pero que realmente representan el mismo trabajo.

Comment: Peter Taylor en su respuesta *no* afirma que "...las traducciones hechas por los compañeros no son correctas"; tan solo menciona que, *en España*, "Computer Science" no se traduce tal como ha dicho Nicolás en su respuesta. Sería bueno además mencionar, de manera más explícita, que esta respuesta hace referencia al uso en España.

Comment: Decir que un desarrollador de software y un programador hacen lo mismo es como decir que un arquitecto y un albañil hacen lo mismo. ¡Así está la profesión! (Es un poco off-topic, pero atañe a la pregunta que se hace)

Answer (score 0):

Translation:

- Computer Science — Informática (Ingeniería Informática)
- Software Engineer — Ingenierío de software
- Software Developer — Desarollador de software
- Programado — Programador

Standard software engineer hierarchy used in Spain (from lowest to highest), with their corresponding acronym:

- Programador Junior  (PJ)
- Programador Senior  (PS)
- Analista Programador (AP)
- Analista Organico (AO)
- Analista Funcional (AF)
- Jefe de Proyecto (JP)

Answer (score -1):

- *Computer Science* --> Ciencias de la computación
- *Software Engineer* --> Ingeniero de Software
- *Software Developer*  --> Desarrollador de Software
- *Programmer* --> Programador

I should add that in some countries, Colombia, for example, universities don't offer a Computer Science major; they usually offer *Ingeniería de Sistemas*, which I guess you could translate as *Systems Engineer* even though compared to the American curriculum is closer to the Computer Engineering or the Computer Science degree; therefore, I usually translate *Computer Scientist* as *Ingeniero de Sistemas*.

Comment: It seems like at least the [Universidad de los Andes](http://sistemas.uniandes.edu.co/sitio/pregrados) in Bogota has started using _Ingeniería de Sistemas y Computación_. I've always disliked the name _Ingeniería de Sistemas_ because it is confusing when translated. Hopefully they will soon start differentiating between _Computer Science_, _Computer Engineering_, and _Information Technology_.

Comment: *Desarrollador* has a double-l.

Comment: @peter Taylor yes! Thanks, I was going to fix it but Joze was kind enough to do it first.